# HTTPS handshake_failure on safari 9

Tags: ssl, https, safari, handshake

I have a couple of websites that uses ssl.
They are all running the same type of certificates, some of them work with safari 9 and some not working right now even though they used to work perfectly.
The ones who stop working run on a shard hosting, could it be the problem?
The ssllabs report for more data:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.israwords.co.il

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen from the [SSLLabs report for site](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.israwords.co.il) this sites only support DHE ciphers. And from the [SSLLabs report for Safari 9](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Safari&version=9&platform=OS%20X%2010.11&key=111) can be seen that the browser does not support DHE ciphers. This together means that there are no shared ciphers and thus the handshake fails. This is unrelated to the certificate but a problem of the web server configuration.

Comment: I see, so i need to contact my hosting company to change the chip set?

Comment: @Raz: it has nothing to do with hardware (chip set) but is a server configuration only. Just ask your hosting company to configure the server as recommended by major organizations, for example https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS. And also asks them to fix the server setup so that the SSLLabs report shows at least an A.

Comment: Thanks, i will contact them